# data structure in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have error on line 10 could tell me what is my mistake. Is it a boolean problem? I tried various solutions but I still get the same error:

```
<?php

class classData {

    function __construct() {
        mysql_select_db("dbVentas", mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""));
    }

    function voidInsert($code, $name) {
        if (validateCodigo($code) == true) {
            mysql_query("insert into tbZone (code,zone) values ('" . $code . "','" . $name . "')")
                    or die("ERROR!!!... ");
        }
    }

    function validateCodigo($code) {
        $ok = true;
        $isql = mysql_query("select * from tbZone where code='" . $code . "'");
        $cCod = 0;

        while ($oRow = mysql_fetch_array($isql)) {
            extract($oRow);
            $cCod++;
        }

        if ($cCod > 0) {
            $ok = false;
        }

        return $ok;
    }
}
?>
```

I call this php file DataClass.php

Comment: mysql_* fuctions are deprecated. Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

Comment: what does the error message say specifically? qué dice el mensaje de error?

Comment: Do you mean there is a syntax error on line 10 or that the query function is returning false and the die() statement is running?

Comment: Why don't you actually echo out the mysql error message to find out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling another class method, you should use

`$this->validateCodigo($code)` instead of `validateCodigo($code)`